# ES6 Alternate While Loop

Tags: javascript, recursion, alternate

I have the following code I've been developing, an alternate `while` loop:

`_while = (cond, act) => cond && act() & _while(cond, act)`

In this case `act()` is intended to alter the end result of `cond` with each iteration until `cond` is evaluated to `false`, to which then the loop is meant to end...

I've tried to test this out by attempting to determine the length of a string through stepping through the string using my code. As a result, my code is the following:

`len = 0; _while(!!("qwerty")[len], ()=>++len);`

Now, my thoughts were that this code will basically step through and test for the presence of each character within the string, incrementing `len` until it attempts `"qwe"[6]` which is `undefined`, and the `!!` renders the `undefined` returned value to `false`, exiting the loop, with the value of `len` being equal to `6`...

However, I'm not even getting that far... for some reason this loop keeps going, and gives up with an error of `InternalError: too much recursion`

Can anyone see what I've done wrong with my code? I'd like to preserve what I can of my original code without having to resort to a native `for` or `while` loop...

Comment: Why are you using a bitwise `&`? I ask because it's the only thing preventing this from being tail-recursive, which will be important if you use this to loop a large number of times.

Comment: Except from that fact that you are using arrow functions, this really doesn't have much to do with ES6.

Comment: @loganfsmyth the `&&` acts as a lazy "if then execute", whereas the lone `&` acts as a lazy statement chainer... Do you have any suggestions to improve on this code?

Comment: @FelixKling A valid point, I'm actually using ES6 to take advantage of the "function"-less function format... I'm working on a little project that uses non-alphanumeric JavaScript... The original version of my `_while` loop code was:

`$_=($,_)=>$()&&_()&$_($,_)` which is a lot less readable...

Comment: Comma :) `_while = (cond, act) => cond() && (act(), _while(cond, act))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `!!("qwerty")[len])` is evaluated before the call to `_while` is actually made. At that time, `len` is `0`, so the result of the expression will be `true`.

To fix this, you could require `cond` to be a function, much like `act` is. This way, you can evaluate the condition each time through the loop. I guess it would look like this (though I'm not JavaScript savvy):

```
_while = (cond, act) => cond() && act() & _while(cond, act)
```

The given example would then become

```
len = 0; _while(()=>!!("qwerty")[len], ()=>++len);
```

Comment: Ken, That's actually worked rather well... I'll hopefully be able to implement this further... Thanks